# How do I use @InjectMocks with a Parameterized test

Tags: java, dependency-injection, mockito, parameterized

Note: I have done a search and read various blogs, but cannot find an example that matches what I am trying to do.

I have a ConverterService which uses a CodeService that is injected into it. I am attempting to write a JUnit test in which I mock the CodeService and inject that mock into the ConverterService under test. The test is Parameterized.

Consider the following code:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ConverterServiceTest {

    @Parameters(name="{index}; Test case {0}")
    public static Collection<Object[]> initTestCases() {
        final Object[][] testCases = {
                { "One",   "First",   TypeEnum.ONE   },
                { "Two",   "Second",  TypeEnum.TWO   },
                { "Three", "Third",   TypeEnum.THREE },
                { "Four",  "Fourth",  TypeEnum.FOUR  },
                { "Five",  "Fifth",   TypeEnum.FIVE  },
                { "Six",   "Unknown", TypeEnum.BLANK }
        };
        return Arrays.asList(testCases);
    }

    @Parameter(0) private String   testName;
    @Parameter(1) private String   testCode;
    @Parameter(2) private TypeEnum expectedCode;

    @Rule public ExpectedException expected = ExpectedException.none();
    @Mock private CodeService codeService;
    @InjectMocks private ConverterService converter;

    @Before public void beforeEach() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        when(codeService.isOne(anyString())).thenReturn(false);
        when(codeService.isOne("First")).thenReturn(true);

        when(codeService.isTwo(anyString())).thenReturn(false);
        when(codeService.isTwo("Second")).thenReturn(true);

        when(codeService.isThree(anyString())).thenReturn(false);
        when(codeService.isThree("Third")).thenReturn(true);

        when(codeService.isFour(anyString())).thenReturn(false);
        when(codeService.isFour("Fourth")).thenReturn(true);

        when(codeService.isFive(anyString())).thenReturn(false);
        when(codeService.isFive("Fifth")).thenReturn(true);
    }

    @Test public void testCodeConverter() {
        assertThat(converter.convert(testCode), equalTo(expectedCode));
    }
}
```

I am using the Parameterized.class runner, I am using MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this), my @Before is initialising the mock CodeService, but I am not getting injection into ConverterService. In fact I am getting some strange reflection errors:

> java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class
>   org.junit.runners.parameterized.BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParameters
>   can not access a member of class
>   com.company.converter.ConverterServiceTest with modifiers "private"
>     at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:102)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.slowCheckMemberAccess(AccessibleObject.java:296)
>     at
>   java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:288)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:761)  at
>   org.junit.runners.parameterized.BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParameters.createTestUsingFieldInjection(BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParameters.java:62)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.parameterized.BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParameters.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParameters.java:36)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)     at
>   org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)  at
>   org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

It seems to not like one of my test member fields being private, but is not telling me which one it has a problem with. All examples of unit tests I have seen, the only public must be the ExpectedException rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I am a dufus. The issue is the @Parameter(x) internal members need to be public, not private.

I spent an age searching Google for that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this code safe my life

```
@Before
public void beforeEach() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```